# Can't insert a int value in a decimal column SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, decimal

Currently working on a school project.

I'm trying to create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Purchase (
ID INT NOT NULL,
Type INT DEFAULT 3 NOT NULL,
Price DECIMAL(5,5) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT check_3 CHECK (TYPE = 3),
CONSTRAINT price_check CHECK (Cost>0),
CONSTRAINT pk_1 PRIMARY KEY (ID),
CONSTRAINT fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (ID,Type) REFERENCES Part(ID,Type));
```

My problem is when I'm trying to insert values into this column.
When I try to do this:

```
INSERT INTO Purchase VALUES (12, 3, 200);
```

I get the following error:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO Purchase VALUES (12, 3, 200);
INSERT INTO Purchase VALUES (12, 3, 200)
                                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong. Can't I add integers to a decimal column? Is that the problem? Doesn't make much sense to me.

Thank you for taking the time to read this!

Comment: Scale and precision [are explained in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-75209AF6-476D-4C44-A5DC-5FA70D701B78).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, always list the columns for an `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO Purchase (id, type, price)
    VALUES (12, 3, 200);
```

Second, your price is declared as `DECIMAL(5, 5)`.  That means that the prices range from 0.00000 to 0.99999.

Presumably, you want a broader range.  I don't know what that is, but `DECIMAL(10, 5)` would solve your problem.  More generally, just `NUMBER` solves your problem in Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

DECIMAL(5,5) means you will recieve space for 5 number after the comma (5 of 5). Please try to create your table like that: DECIMAL(10,5)